# Convert list to string with single quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am trying to create a string from List

This is my code

```
 List<string> SelectedSalesmen = new  List<string>();
```

and I am adding selected salesmen from listBox like this

```
foreach (ListItem lst in lstBoxSalesmen.Items)
            {
                if (lst.Selected)
                {

                    SelectedSalesmen.Add(lst.Value);
                }
            }
```

finally I am storing that value to a string like this

```
 string SalesManCode = string.Join(",", SelectedSalesmen.ToArray());
```

But I am getting like this

```
SLM001,SLM002,SLM003
```

but I need Output like this

```
'SLM001','SLM002','SLM003'
```

Comment: [use string builder and append in that accordingly why to use list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076454/string-builder-vs-lists)

Comment: does any answer helped you?

Comment: Use join with ' to merge the list

Answer (score 54):

Try this:

```
string SalesManCode = string.Join(",", SelectedSalesmen
                                            .Select(x=>string.Format("'{0}'",x)));
```

it will wrap all your elements with `'` and then join them using `,` as separator

Comment: why isnt this answer at the top?

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

```
string output = "'" + string.Join("','", SelectedSalesmen) + "'";
```

Though this'll return `''` for an empty input.

Comment: Tricky solution, I haven't thought about it :)

Answer (score 4):

Same as the answer from @wudzik but with string interpolation

```
var salesManCode = string.Join(",", selectedSalesmen.Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
```

Comment: I like this better than using `string.Format`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the above one with split like below:

```
string.Join(",", SelectedSalesmen.Split(',').Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)));
```

which will give you:

```
"'SLM001','SLM002','SLM003'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
string.Join(",", elements.Select(element => $"'{element}'"));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```
"'" + string.Joing("',", SelectedSalesmen.ToArray() + "'");
```