# c# mysql get all rows

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm just getting the last line when I do it like below

How can I get all the rows

```
baglanti.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from lisans", baglanti);
        int Count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (Count != 0)
        {

        MySqlDataReader oku = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (oku.Read())
        {
               textBox1.Text= oku.GetString("mac");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. You loop over the results and replace the content of the TextBox with the current value in the loop. In this way only the value of the last record will be seen in the textbox.

If you want to have all the records in a textbox then you need something like this

```
List<string> macs = new List<string>();
while (oku.Read())
{
       macs.Add(oku.GetString("mac"));
}
textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", macs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Microsoft MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Consider using the StringBuilder class under these conditions:

•When you expect your app to make an unknown number of changes to a string at design time (for example, when you are using a loop to concatenate a random number of strings that contain user input).

•When you expect your app to make a significant number of changes to a string.

The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (oku.Read())
{
   sb.Append(oku.GetString("mac"));
   sb.Append(";");
}
textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you have evidence that StringBuilder is better?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076454/string-builder-vs-lists and https://blog.goyello.com/2013/01/07/8-most-common-mistakes-c-developers-make/