# How to construct range string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert list to number range string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688881/convert-list-to-number-range-string)

Assume I have the following code:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
//myValues are of type List<string>
for(int i=0; i<myValues.count; i++)
{
  string myVal = myValues[i];
  if (myVal=="testing")
  {
    ints.Add(i+1);
  }
}

String.Join (", ", ints);
```

This will result is something like this:

```
1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,14
```

I'm looking for a way to display values like this instead:

```
1-3, 6-10, 14
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the logic is not clear: why first range is `1-3` and second is `6-10` ?

Comment: @Tigran - Ranges of contiguous integers.

Comment: There is nothing built in - you will have to write your own function.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688881/convert-list-to-number-range-string

Comment: By the way "Any suggestions?" is not really the kind of question we expect. We expect to see what you have tries and for you to at least explain where you are stuck. To answer your question - my suggestion is that you write your own function for this...

Comment: might i have your answer in place of String.Join (", ", ints); use my below comment  code and get your answer

Comment: string result ="";
if(ints!=null)
{int intial=ints[0]; int status=0; result= ints[0];
for(int i=1;i<ints.count;i++)
{ if(intial !=ints[i]-1)
   { if(status==0){result=result+"-"+ints[i]}else{}result=result+","+ints[i]}

Comment: I actually posted a new answer on the thread the mods forwarded you to. It does what you're seeking.