# Covert List<int> to a list of ranges

Tags: c#, list, range

I need to convert a `list` of integers to a list of ranges.

I have a `List<int>` that contains `8, 22, 41`.  These values are the *section breaks* in a complete list from `1` to `47`.

I am trying to get a list of ranges that contains a start line and end line.  The output should be

```
{(1,7),(8,21),(22,40),(41,47)}
```

I have tried to *adapt the solution* from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688881/convert-list-to-number-range-string) but can't get it to work.

Seems like it should be simple, but maybe not.

Comment: Forgot the tag for C#

Comment: Just as a general tip, if I were in this scenario I would probably make a custom class / struct called `Section` and then have the method implementing this behavior return a `List<Section>` or `Section[]` instead of a `Tuple<int,int>[]`; 
the Tuple array method will be functional, but you can give a custom type like `Section` a `Start` and `End` field / property which is more descriptive than `Item1`, `Item2`, etc, and more readable (IMO) in the long run.

Comment: Actually that is what I was trying to do.  Kept winding up with garbage code.  I will integrate the tuple concept into the class.

Comment: If you want, I can write something that would be fairly clean using a setup like that. The class could contain a Tuple but personally I'd prefer just having separate, well named properties / fields. (I'd probably make `readonly` fields)

Comment: What if the section breaks include 1? What if they include 47?  What if they include 46?  What if they include numbers greater than 47 or less than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *Linq*; assuming that range is of type `Tuple<int, int>`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 8, 22, 41};

int from = 1;
int upTo = 47;

var result = list
  .OrderBy(item => item)          // to be on the safe side in case of {22, 8, 41}  
  .Concat(new int[] { upTo + 1 }) // add upTo breaking point
  .Select(item => new Tuple<int, int>(from, (from = item) - 1));
//  .ToArray(); // in case you want to get materialized result (array)

Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
(1, 7)
(8, 21)
(22, 40)
(41, 47)
```

Comment: The tricky part is `(from = item) - 1`. You have to know that C# has not only an assignment statement but also the assignment expression yielding the assigned value as result and doing the assignment as a side-effect.

Comment: Yeah, that is confusing.

Comment: **NEVER DO THIS**.  Never write a query that mutates a local as it runs!  That is incredibly dangerous.  Though in this particular case it works, even small changes to such queries start producing crazy results.

Comment: @EricLippert What can occur by from mutating a local as it runs, isn't that just a closure?

Comment: @johnny5: Yes, it is precisely because it is a closure that we have a problem! Let's look at some examples. Suppose we have a sequence of strings and we wish to have a sequence of ints where we replace non-ints with zero. So we need a `bool` that says whether a string is an int, and the value if it is, hey, `TryParse` does that but it requires that we mutate a local. So we foolishly write `var seq = new[]{ "1", "blah", "3" }; int tmp = 0; 
var nums = 
  from item in seq   
  let success = int.TryParse(item, out tmp)   
  select success ? tmp : 0;` ... and it works.

Comment: @johnny5: And then some *maintenance programmer*, that is, johnny5 twenty minutes in the future, modifies this *legacy code* -- legacy code being code that was *written in the past* -- because the customer wants them *sorted by the original string order*.  So we modify the query because *LINQ is awesome* and write `from item in seq let success = int.TryParse(item, out tmp) orderby item select success ? tmp : 0` and the query is now *completely wrong*. **Adding an orderby should not make a query wrong**, but that's what happens when you mutate a local!

Comment: @johnny5: If it is not clear why the query is now completely wrong, then hey, that's another reason why mutating locals in a query is bad: **it makes it so johnny5 cannot read a query and know that it is totally wrong at a glance**. If you're still not clear on why the query is wrong, make a dot net fiddle and run it; were you surprised by the results? Do you understand why closure semantics demand that this be the result? If yes, awesome, you know why this is wrong. If no, then again we have points against doing this, because it makes programs that are not understandable by smart people.

Comment: @johnny5: Now how might we solve the problem correctly? We avoid mutating the local by mutating it *in another method entirely:* `static int? MyTryParse(this string item) {
  int tmp;
  bool success = int.TryParse(item, out tmp);
  return success ? (int?)tmp : (int?)null; 
}`  And now our query is `var nums = 
  from item in seq 
  select item.MyTryParse() ?? 0;` and the query can now be edited to our heart's content without ever worrying that we'll introduce a bug because of closure semantics, because there are no closure semantics.

Answer (score 6):

Answers which state that you should mutate a local during a query are dangerous even if the program works; do not get into this bad habit.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to write an iterator block. Let's suppose you have the obvious `Pair<T>` type; in C# 7 you would likely use a tuple; adapting this to use tuples is an easy exercise:

```
static IEnumerable<Pair<int>> MakeIntervals(
  /* this */ IEnumerable<int> dividers, /* You might want an extension method.*/
  int start,
  int end)
{
  // Precondition: dividers is not null, but may be empty.
  // Precondition: dividers is sorted.  
  // If that's not true in your world, order it here.
  // Precondition: dividers contains no value equal to or less than start.
  // Precondition: dividers contains no value equal to or greater than end.
  // If it is possible for these preconditions to be violated then
  // the problem is underspecified; say what you want to happen in those cases.
  int currentStart = start;
  for (int divider in dividers) 
  {
    yield return new Pair<int>(currentStart, divider - 1);
    currentStart = divider;
  }
  yield return new Pair<int>(currentStart, end);
}
```

That's the right way to solve this problem. If you wanted to get a bit silly you could use `Zip`. Start with two helpful extension methods:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T first)
{
  yield return first;
  foreach(T item in items) yield return item;
}
static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T last)
{
  foreach(T item in items) yield return item;
  yield return last;
}
```

And now we have:

```
static IEnumerable<Pair<int>> MakeIntervals(
  IEnumerable<int> dividers,
  int start,
  int end)
{
  var starts = dividers.Prepend(start);
  // This is the sequence 1, 8, 22, 41
  var ends = dividers.Select(d => d - 1).Append(end);
  // This is the sequence 7, 21, 40, 47
  var results = starts.Zip(ends, (s, e) => new Pair<int>(s, e));
  // Zip them up: (1, 7), (8, 21), (22, 40), (41, 47)
  return results;
}
```

But this seems needlessly baroque compared to simply writing the iterator block directly. Also, this iterates the collection twice, which is considered by many to be bad style.

A cute way to solve the problem is to generalize the first solution:

```
static IEnumerable<R> SelectPairs<T, R>(
  this IEnumerable<T> items,
  Func<T, T, R> selector
)
{
  bool first = true;
  T previous = default(T);
  foreach(T item in items) {
    if (first) {
      previous = item;
      first = false;
    }
    else
    {
      yield return selector(previous, item);
      previous = item;
    }
  }
}
```

And now your method is:

```
static IEnumerable<Pair<int>> MakeIntervals(
  IEnumerable<int> dividers,
  int start,
  int end)
{
  return dividers
    .Prepend(start)
    .Append(end + 1)
    .SelectPairs((s, e) => new Pair<int>(s, e - 1);
}
```

I quite like that last one.  That is, we are given `8, 22, 41`, we construct `1, 8, 22, 41, 48`, and then from that we pick off pairs and construct `(1, 7), (8, 21),`  and so on.

Comment: @WouldRatherBuildAMotor This answer is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't very clean but you could build a new array and loop to fill in the blanks. This assumes your numbers are sorted coming in and I used a `Tuple<int, int>` return because I couldn't find any simple range types that made sense. With this code you dont have to worry about storing the state in a variable outside of the loop variable and you don't need to exclude any results.

```
public Tuple<int, int>[] GetRanges(int start, int end, params int[] input)
{
    // Create new array that includes a slot for the start and end number
    var combined = new int[input.Length + 2];
    // Add input at the first index to allow start number
    input.CopyTo(combined, 1);
    combined[0] = start;
    // Increment end to account for subtraction later
    combined[combined.Length - 1] = end + 1;

    // Create new array of length - 1 (think fence-post, |-|-|-|-|)
    Tuple<int, int>[] ranges = new Tuple<int, int>[combined.Length - 1];
    for (var i = 0; i < combined.Length - 1; i += 1) {
        // Create a range of the number and the next number minus one
        ranges[i] = new Tuple<int, int>(combined[i], combined[i+1] - 1);
    }

    return ranges;
}
```

**Usage**

```
GetRanges(1, 47, 8, 22, 41);
```

or

```
GetRanges(1, 47, new [] { 8, 22, 41 });
```

If you would like an alternative pure-linq solution you could use this,

```
public Tuple<int, int>[] GetRanges(int start, int end, params int[] input)
{       
    return input
        .Concat(new [] { start, end + 1 }) // Add first and last numbers, adding one to end to include it in the range
        .SelectMany(i => new [] { i, i - 1 }) // Generate "end" numbers for each start number
        .OrderBy(i => i)
        .Except(new [] {start - 1, end + 1}) // Exclude pre-first and post-last numbers
        .Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }) // Gather information to bucket values
        .GroupBy(p => p.Index / 2) // Create value buckets
        .Select(g => new Tuple<int, int>(g.First().Value, g.Last().Value)) // Convert each bucket into a Tuple
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This returns (1,7)  (8,21)  (22,40)  (41,46)  The last item, 47, is not included.

Comment: Sorry about that. You can add one to the end number to account for that. I updated my answer.

Comment: I accepted the previous linq answer, it was first and works.   However some very basic testing shows your method is much faster
Linq: TotalMilliseconds: 4.0944

Array: TotalMilliseconds: 0.225

Comment: @WouldRatherBuildAMotor: The Linq solution here is very over-engineered; it could be a lot simpler.

Comment: @EricLippert Fair enough, it was a bit of an after thought because I didn't like the other answers Linq. It sounds like they liked my non-linq answer though. It looks like your answer covered my concerns as far as that went though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `C#` [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1) and `C# 8.0` [Ranges and indices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) along with new [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions), the solution can be done in a bit nifty way by creating handy [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Integer List array extensions.
/// </summary>
public static class RangesExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates list of ranges from single dimension ranges list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ranges">Single dimension ranges list.</param>
    /// <param name="from">Range first item.</param>
    /// <param name="to">Range last item.</param>
    /// <returns>List of ranges.</returns>
    public static List<(int, int)> ToListOfRanges(
        this List<int> ranges,
        int from,
        int to)
    {
        var list = ranges.ToArray();

        return list.OrderBy(item => item)
                   .Select((item, index) => GetNext(ranges, from, index))
                   .Append((list[^1], to))
                   .ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns next couple of ranges from initial array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ranges">Single dimension ranges list.</param>
    /// <param name="from">Range first item.</param>
    /// <param name="index">Range current item index.</param>
    /// <returns>Value Tuple of ranges.</returns>
    private static (int, int) GetNext(
        List<int> ranges,
        int from,
        int index)
    {
        return index switch
        {
            0 => (from, ranges[index] - 1),
            _ => (ranges[index - 1], ranges[index] - 1),
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify the target language. So, in Scala, one way of doing so is:

```
val breaks = List(8, 22, 41)
val range = (1, 47)

val ranges = (breaks :+ (range._2 + 1)).foldLeft((range._1, List.empty[(Int, Int)])){
  case ((start, rangesAcc), break) => (break, rangesAcc :+ (start, break - 1))
}

println(ranges._2)
```

Which prints: `List((1,7), (8,21), (22,40), (41,47))`

Alternatively, we can use recursion:

```
def ranges(rangeStart: Int, rangeEnd: Int, breaks: List[Int]) = {
  @tailrec
  def ranges(start: Int, breaks: List[Int], rangesAcc: List[(Int, Int)]): List[(Int, Int)] = breaks match {
    case break :: moreBreaks => ranges(break, moreBreaks, rangesAcc :+ (start, break - 1))
    case nil => rangesAcc :+ (start, rangeEnd)
  }
  ranges(rangeStart, breaks, List.empty[(Int, Int)])
}
```

Comment: You didnt specify your target language.