# Is there a parser that interprets colon and comma notation?

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I'm new to using Using boost::program_options, and I'd like to parse a numeric command line argument with colon and comma notation.  For example i'd like to have this kind of argument:

```
myprogram --numbers 1:100,200,300
```

Produce a vector with the integers 1-100 then 200 and finally 300.

Is there a name for this notation?

My first inclination is that I'd have to treat this argument as a string, then pass it to a function function that does the parsing.  It seems like this is  an excellent candidate for "somthing someone has done already and made available."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does C# have built-in support for parsing page-number strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161/does-c-sharp-have-built-in-support-for-parsing-page-number-strings)

Comment: Sounds like a great job for regex

Answer (score 0):

I would use [boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/warming_up.html) and define some custom [semantic actions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html). Make sure the version of boost::spirit you use is compatible with the compiler with this. I've had issues with using newer boost::spirit with older compilers. Matlab calls the 1:5 "colon notation". Pretty anti-climactic eh?