# How to unfold a string into a list of objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to allow a user to provide a URL in the following format:

`http://siteexample.com/?id=[1-7]&parameter=[a-dk-p]`

Then I want to be able to do something in my code for every matching URL. For this reason I want to unfold the placeholders into lists of objects, where the first one contains: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` and the second one: `a, b, c, d, k, l, m, n, o, p` and then use them in `foreach` loops. I am thinking about writing my own class to do that and I want to comply with regular expressions.

Does anyone have any experience with it or maybe knows something that already exists? I don't want to reinvent the wheel and somehow I cannot imagine that no one has ever need it before...Unfortunately I cannot find anything on the Internet (maybe I am using wrong keywords).

Comment: You're looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161/does-c-sharp-have-built-in-support-for-parsing-page-number-strings)

Comment: As @JeroenVannevel said, write some classes. Its going to be quicker than trying to find something... Your won;t be re-inventing the wheel, you would be creating a class. Re-doing the .net mail class, would be re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: OK, thanks! I am rolling my own stuff :-)